# How to fix the error org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null, when using RestTemplate to access Microservice

Tags: java, json, spring, http, httpresponse

In my java code, I am trying to access a microservice using `RestTemplate` as the following:

```
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    entity = new HttpEntity<BigDecimal>(c.getDocumentId(),headers);                     
    ResponseEntity<String> response =    restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8082/document-external-id", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    String externalId= response.getBody();
```

On the server side, I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/document-external-id", method=RequestMethod.POST)

String getExternalDocumentId(@RequestBody  BigDecimal documentId)
{
    System.out.println("Documents External Id Microservice called.....Params are:"+documentId);

    Documents document =documentsService.findDocumentById(documentId);//invoke the method to get the document

    System.out.println("Documents External Id microservice is DONE!.......................................Returning value:"+document.getExternalDocumentId());

    return document.getExternalDocumentId();

}
```

When I run my code, here's the output with the error on the client side, which occurs at this line:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response =    restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8082/document-external-id", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:539)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.controller.util.CircularsControllerUtil.circularListView(CircularsControllerUtil.java:151)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.controller.CircularsController.viewCircularList(CircularsController.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:335)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:610)
    at ae.gov.adm.common.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
400 null
```

On the server side, I have the following output with a Warning message:

```
Documents External Id Microservice called.....Params are:9191
2020-02-06 12:18:19.086  WARN 1752 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.doc_master_id as doc_master_id2_0_0_, this_.entry_id as entry_id3_0_0_, this_.external_doc_id as external_doc_id4_0_0_, this_.file_path as file_path5_0_0_, this_.name as name6_0_0_, this_.server_address as server_address7_0_0_, this_.type as type8_0_0_, this_.upload_date as upload_date9_0_0_ from mu_documents this_ where this_.id=?
Documents External Id microservice is DONE!.......................................Returning value:{A66CD1F8-839F-432F-9C9C-4EAE961A8F46}
2020-02-06 12:18:19.135  WARN 1752 --- [nio-8082-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: java.lang.String ae.gov.adm.DocumentsMicroservice.getExternalDocumentId(java.math.BigDecimal)]
```

How to fix the error? Thanks.

Comment: Your service responds with a 400-Bad Request because _Required request body is missing: java.lang.String ae.gov.adm.DocumentsMicroservice.getExternalDocumentId(java.math.BigDecimal)_. So it would seem that your request is missing the correct request body. I would check what the service really defines as body and compare it with the body you send.

Comment: As you can see above, the service requests a BigDecimal as parameter and I am sending BigDecimal as parameter. What could be else missing? And where to check other than the service method parameter. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: By the way, when I removed @RequestBody  the error is gone, but the service doesn't receive the parameter sent by the client. The parameter value is null

Comment: If you remove @RequestBody there is no required RequestBody, that's why it "works". Did you check if _c.getDocumentId()_ is null?

Comment: @lugiorgi, it will be null when I remove RequestBody annotation, but when I keep it, it is not null. It has a value and you can see it printed in the code and in the server output above. "Documents External Id Microservice called.....Params are:9191". So the value is BigDecimal 9191, that's why it is weird

Comment: Can you post the serverside stacktrace?

Comment: I printed the complete output. On the server side there is no error, it is a warning, and I provided it above. I don't know whether there is a way to get more information

Comment: DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handles the exception and prints the warning message. There you could also print the stacktrace (if you have access to the code).
I tried to reproduce your error but to no avail. I copy pasted your code except _documentsService.findDocumentById(documentId)_ and the Document class. Maybe your error lies there?

Comment: I think you are right...

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the value null of some document ids causes the problem. Perhaps, because @RequestBody does not accept a null value.

Here's the update to fix the problem:

```
  if(documentId!=null)
                        {
                            headers = new HttpHeaders();
                            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                            entity = new HttpEntity<BigDecimal>(documentId,headers);                        
                            ResponseEntity<String> response =    restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8082/document-name", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
                            documentName= response.getBody();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with an annotation like:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/document-external-id", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getExternalDocumentId(@RequestBody  BigDecimal documentId){

       System.out.println("Documents External Id Microservice called.....Params are:"+documentId);

       Documents document =documentsService.findDocumentById(documentId);//invoke the method to get the document

       System.out.println("Documents External Id microservice is DONE!.......................................Returning value:"+document.getExternalDocumentId());

       return document.getExternalDocumentId();
}
```